# Stopped accepting connections from outside the local network

Tags: networking, server, ssh, iptables

I have multiple services running on the server: https/XMPP/SSH.

I have logon to the http server over the WAN once today but now nothing is able to connect.
Now I'm at home and I've tested it again, all services are still available via LAN connection.

When I tried to access my server via https over WAN, I got prompted for my self-signed certificate, which I clicked continue and the page got stuck on loading.

My iptable is not on, my ports are not blocked by my ISP(http://canyouseeme.org/).

Edit: Tried it again, I can SSH to the server via WAN.
nmap shows both 443 and 80 are open.

Comment: What services exactly are you trying to reach from the outside? How are they configured? What is your NAT configuration? Please expand your question.

Comment: Do you have a dedicated firewall running?